# DocuSign API - GetEnvelopeDocuments - get file size without downloading?

Tags: docusignapi

According to : https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/list/

The EnvelopeDocument model should have "sizeBytes" property on it.

However, I'm making calls to `GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}/documents`
and the payload does not have it.

I also tried hitting `HEAD https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}/documents/{{documentId}`
to see if I could read the headers without the actual content but that I receive a 404 NOT FOUND so it must not be supported.

The only way I can see to accomplish this would be to hit the download file endpoint directly, reading the content-length header, and then cancelling the request before streaming any data from it.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to make a get envelope call
GET [https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}/documents](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7B%7BaccountId%7D%7D/envelopes/%7B%7BenvelopeId%7D/documents)

Then in the headers, you will find Content-Length, this is the file size

Comment: Thanks Yarak, but the content-length of the entire GET envelopeDocuments request is not the size of the file(s), its the length of the data being returned from that request.

Comment: Then the only solution would be to hit the download file endpoint directly.

Answer (score 0):

Reached out to DocuSign and they confirmed there's no way to do this other than to hit the download endpoint and read the content length header.

After some experimentation i found this doesnt really work either because the Content Length header is not always accurate from their api.  The only way I can see to do it is to download the entire file into memory and take a count of the bytes, or keep track of the byte count as you stream it to its destination.